# Join tables - show every row of the left table only once and add a row with data that is not connected to the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table that look like this:

products:

```
order_id  prices

_______  _____

2          20

3          11

null       40
```

Orders:

```
id number

1      30

2      50

3      10

4      10
```

I want to get the following table:

```
id      number  price

--      ------  -----


1       30      null

2       50      20

3       10      11

4       10      null

null(0) null(0) 40
```

foreign key are obviously the order_id -> orders. can be null.

As you probably can see i want to include all the rows from table orders if there is a link to products combine them.
and if there is no link just show null and the '40' (sum of 'disconnected' products)

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is `id` unique in the `orders` table? If yes what do you mean by "only once" in your question's title?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `full join`:

```
select o.id o.number, p.price
from orders o full join
     products p
     on p.order_id = o.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left join` from `orders` to `products` and `union` with the `products` that have `null` as `order_id`:

```
select o.id, o.number, p.prices
from orders o left join products p
on p.order_id = o.id
union all
select null, null, p.prices
from products p
where p.order_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the orders

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.number
FROM orders;

 id | number 
----+--------
  1 |     30
  2 |     50
  3 |     10
  4 |     10
```

Retrieve the prices associated to orders

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.number, products.prices
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products ON orders.id = products.order_id;

 id | number | prices 
----+--------+--------
  1 |     30 |        
  2 |     50 |     20 
  3 |     10 |     11 
  4 |     10 |
```

Retrieve the prices associated to orders as well as the products without order associated

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.number, products.prices
FROM orders
FULL JOIN products ON orders.id = products.order_id;

 id | number | prices 
----+--------+--------
  1 |     30 |       
  2 |     50 |     20
  3 |     10 |     11
    |        |     40
  4 |     10 |
```

Sum the prices with no order associated. We see no difference here since there is only one product with no order associated (the one where `order_id` is null), but you asked for the sum of these prices so here you go :-)

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.number, SUM(products.prices) AS prices
FROM orders
FULL JOIN products ON orders.id = products.order_id
GROUP BY orders.id, orders.number;

 id | number | prices 
----+--------+--------
  1 |     30 |       
  2 |     50 |     20
  3 |     10 |     11
    |        |     40
  4 |     10 |
```

Use your null(0) label and order by id

```
SELECT
  coalesce(orders.id::varchar(255), 'null(0)') AS id,
  coalesce(orders.number::varchar(255), 'null(0)') AS number,
  SUM(products.prices) AS prices
FROM orders
FULL JOIN products ON orders.id = products.order_id
GROUP BY orders.id, orders.number
ORDER BY id;

   id    | number  | prices 
---------+---------+--------
 1       | 30      |       
 2       | 50      |     20
 3       | 10      |     11
 4       | 10      |       
 null(0) | null(0) |     40
```